# Read data into pandas data frame whilst maintaining a high number of decimal points

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read some data from text files using pandas read_csv.

The data is of the form:

```
(v14).K         Best_ value
5.00885e-007    3.0914e+007
5.75366e-007    2.99467e+007
```

And my code so far is:

```
def parse_IA_results(results):
    df = pandas.read_csv(results, delimiter='\t',dtype=numpy.float64)
    return df
```

The problem is that this function automatically rounds to 5 decimal places leaving my data imprecise. I tried to use the `dtype=numpy.float` argument but this didn't work. Does anybody know how to read data from a text file into a pandas dataframe whilst maintaining the precision in the data?

Comment: Are you sure that the extra precision is not there?  It may not *display* when you look at the DataFrame as a whole, but if you extract a single value you should see more decimal places.

Comment: Yes, in fact, you are correct. The precision is there but it just doesn't print it to screen. Thanks

Comment: try `pd.set_option('display.precision',20)` this displays more decimal values

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you can specify float_precision (default: float_precision=None).